# Stress in a sentence. Is "some" a determiner in "Get some sleep"?

Tags: pronunciation, determiners, word-stress

As far as I know determiners are not stressed as long as we don't need special emphasis. Am I right? If we don't need special emphasis we only stress the content words "get" and "sleep". Am I right?

Comment: +1 - *BUT* can you wait at least a couple of days before selecting an answer please old bean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, without special emphasis determiners are normally not stressed. The word *some* is **an indefinite determiner** here.

In terms of stress, *sleep* would normally get the primary stress and *get* the secondary stress. This means that *sleep* will be stressed slightly more than *get*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. With no special stress, the word "sleep" would carry the most emphasis. "Some" would be entirely unstressed. A more visual representation might be:

> GET some SLEEP.

Answer (score 1):

> /ˈgɛʔ sm ˈsli:p/

**Determiners**

Most determiners don't usually take stress in normal, unmarked speech. For example, the articles *a* and *the* are very rarely stressed. The same is true of the indefinite determiners *some* and *any*. Many words in determinative function do take stress though. One example is numbers. So in the phrase:

- Two sugars, please

both *two* and the first syllable of *sugars* will usually be stressed.

**Get**

The verb *get* is often described as an 'empty' verb. This is because it often has very little meaning of its own. In *get* passives for example, *GET* seems to have an auxiliary like role, almost. In other sentences such as:

- Ben got an email

*GET* will also not be stressed. It doesn't give us much specific information here.  In the example above we would expect *Ben* and the first syllable of *email* to be stressed, but not the word *stressed*.

However, in the Original Poster's example, *GET* is the main verb in an imperative construction. We normally expect the main verb in an imperative to be stressed (although not necessarily, especially with the verb *BE*). In the phrase:

- Get some sleep

we would normally expect the verb *get* and the lexical noun *sleep* to take stress. The word *some* would not be stressed in a normal, unmarked version of the sentence. Because there is a noun following the word *some* here we would expect to see the weak form /sm/ or perhaps /səm/ here. We would definitely not expect the strong form /sʌm/.

**Prominence**

In terms of the overall sentence, the word *sleep* will get the nuclear tone because it is the last content word. It may therefore be perceived as the most prominent syllable in the utterance. However, it is also perfectly possible for the word *get* to be the loudest or highest pitch syllable here in the onset position. The imperative construction here makes this even more likely. It depends on the context of the utterance.

**Pronunciation note:**

When followed by a noun the word *some* will usually be unstressed and weak. When we see the word *some* without a following noun, as in the sentence:

- Do you want some?

... the word *some* will still be unstressed, but will have a full vowel. In other words the strong form, /sʌm/, is required.